# Spring-Boot subclassing User and findUserByUsername

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm aiming for subclassing Spring's User class, as it already has the standard attributes. One question arises as to how am I supposed to implement a CrudRepository that refers to properties in the User class?

Specifically I'm wondering about the most common use case, namely the findUserByUsername (called by UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername). Here's some code...

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", initialValue = 1)
public class AppUser extends User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
    private long id;


    public AppUser(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Attempting to create the CrudRepository normally, will fail miserably with `Could not query metamodel` upon startup. This makes sense, because the username attribute is not inherited directly to my subclass and User is obviously not marked as @Entity.

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<AppUser, Long> {    
    AppUser findByUsername(String username);    
}
```

## Error message upon startup

> Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract
>   se.riee.user.AppUser
>   se.riee.user.UserRepository.findByUsername(java.lang.String)!

Comment: `User` isn't annotated with `@MappedSuperClass` or `@Entity` so isn't scanned. Either provide XML mappings (`orm.xml`) or don't subclass. Also Spring doesn't have a user class, Spring Security does....

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the answer, sounds cumbersome when you can avoid it. Is it fair to say that subclassing User doesn't really fit well in a web application, at least if you're trying to save to DB?

Comment: The fact that something shares a field doesn't make it the same :). Next to that do you really want to tie your code and domain objects to some 3rd party frameworks ones? Just create your own `User` and let it implement `UserDetails` if you want to use the same object for Spring Security.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing that, thanks. I think the purpose of subclassing User doesn't apply to my case, and it shouldn't be considered as a domain class. Spring Security's User is to abstract an authenticated user within some context X. I guess I was confused about that fact.